# Consulta de Dos Fechas Usando VB Net y SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

Estoy haciendo la consulta de dos fechas pero al momento de Buscar las dos Fechas me aparece ese error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy usando en VB

```
Dim vm_tabla As DataTable = New DataTable
Dim vm_sql As String = ""


Private Sub Frm_Bitacora_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Public Sub Gd_perfil()
    Dim fechaIni As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim fechaFin As String = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim dt As DataTable

    ''' Intervalo para las fechas  
    vm_sql = "Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE  Fecha_Ingreso Between'" + fechaIni + " ' And '" + fechaFin + "' "
    sql.Traer_info_sql(vm_sql, vm_tabla)
    GridControl1.DataSource = vm_tabla

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Gd_perfil()

    GridView1.BestFitColumns()


End Sub
```

Se debe a algún conversion o algo?

Comment: Estimada, te agradecería si pones el modelo de la tabla a donde realizas la consulta y ejemplo de 1 o 2 datos de como se ven los datos dentro.

Comment: Quita los guiones de tu formato de fecha para que quede `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya funcionó

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser por que tu FechaIni y FechaFin estan como cadenas habrá que convertirlos a `datetime` o `date` según el tipo que sea Fecha_Ingreso en sql server con la función `CONVERT`

Ejemplo:

```
vm_sql = "Select * From [KNTB_Bitacora] WHERE  CONVERT(datetime,Fecha_Ingreso) Between CONVERT(datetime,'" + fechaIni + " ') And CONVERT(datetime,'" + fechaFin + "' )"
```

Comment: Me aparece el mismo error

Comment: revisa que fechaIni y fechaFin tengan un formato de fecha

Comment: Fecha_Ingreso que tipo es?

Comment: es `datetime` pero ya lo corregí, muchas gracias